# Product price comparison in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table looks like given below query, I add products price in this table daily, with different sellers name :

```
create table Product_Price
    (
      id int,
      dt date,
      SellerName varchar(20),
      Product varchar(10),
      Price money
    )

    insert into Product_Price values (1, '2012-01-16','Sears','AA', 32)
    insert into Product_Price values (2, '2012-01-16','Amazon', 'AA', 40)
    insert into Product_Price values (3, '2012-01-16','eBay','AA', 27)

    insert into Product_Price values (4, '2012-01-17','Sears','BC', 33.2)
    insert into Product_Price values (5, '2012-01-17','Amazon', 'BC',30)
    insert into Product_Price values (6, '2012-01-17','eBay', 'BC',51.4)

    insert into Product_Price values (7, '2012-01-18','Sears','DE', 13.5)
    insert into Product_Price values (8, '2012-01-18','Amazon','DE', 11.1)
    insert into Product_Price values (9, '2012-01-18', 'eBay','DE', 9.4)
```

I want result like this for n number of sellers(As more sellers added in table)

```
DT           PRODUCT   Sears[My Site]   Amazon   Ebay   Lowest Price
1/16/2012    AA        32               40       27     Ebay
1/17/2012    BC        33.2             30       51.4   Amazon
1/18/2012    DE        7.5              11.1     9.4    Sears
```

Comment: This is easy enough, as long as you know the names of the stores you'll want for columns in advance. But since you want 'n' sellers, you're out of luck. The SQL language really needs to know the number and type of columns for the result set in advance. Anything else requires dynamic sql or (better) a PIVOT on the client side.

Comment: @Joel, in a case like this, what's wrong with dynamic sql?  You aren't building a sql string based on parms input by a user, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Andrew It would avoid first-order injection, but may be vulnerable to 2nd order injection. Someone has to enter the store names. I know that's contrived, though. Mainly, the client-side pivot is still better because it side-steps any other unexplored safety/security issues, but more because it will tend to perform better and the dynamic sql pivot code tends to be harder to understand/maintain. I did upvote your answer, though.

Comment: @Joel, fair enough. And I would certainly agree this kind of thing is way easier in a tool like Crystal, Cognos.  Or put it in a cube, probably even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4bb4/3)

It's kind of ugly, but here's a little breakdown.

This block allows you to get a dynamic list of your values.  (Can't remember who I stole this from, but it's awesome.  Without this, pivot really isn't any better than a big giant case statement approach to this.)

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(SellerName)
                      FROM Product_Price
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '')
```

Your @cols variable comes out like so:

```
[Amazon],[eBay],[Sears]
```

Then you need to build a string of your entire query:

```
select @query = 
'select piv1.*, tt.sellername from (
select *
from
(select dt, product, SellerName,  sum(price) as price from product_price group by  dt, product, SellerName) t1

pivot (sum(price) for SellerName in (' + @cols + '))as bob
) piv1
inner join
(select t2.dt,t2.sellername,t1.min_price from
(select dt,  min(price) as min_price  from product_price group by  dt) t1
inner join (select dt,sellername, sum(price) as price from product_price group by dt,sellername) t2 on t1.min_price = t2.price) tt
on piv1.dt = tt.dt
'
```

The piv1 derived table gets you the pivoted values.  The cleverly named tt derived table gets you the seller who has the minimum sales for each day.
(Told you it was kind of ugly.)

And finally, you run your query:

```
execute(@query)
```

And you get:

```
 DT     PRODUCT     AMAZON  EBAY    SEARS   SELLERNAME
2012-01-16  AA  40  27  32  eBay
2012-01-17  BC  30  51.4    33.2    Amazon
2012-01-18  DE  11.1    9.4     13.5    eBay
```

(sorry, can't make that bit line up).

I would think that if you have a reporting tool that can do crosstabs, this would be a heck of a lot easier to do there.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew just a little more, if you could help herewith, Question 1: Can you please also let me know if there is 4 or 5 or N sellers then what all i need to change in the code. Question 2: if there is 3, 4 more columns in the table then where to write there name to fetch that columns(for example shipping days) also along with this result

Comment: For your first question, you don't have to modify anything for more sellers.  The block that builds the @cols string handles that for you.  If you want to include more columns in your output, in this particular query, you would include them in this part: `(select dt, product, SellerName,  sum(price) as price from product_price group by  dt, product, SellerName) t1`.

Comment: Hey Andrew, I need to exclude SELLERNAME columns, because it's giving duplicate entry in output when 2-3 sellers are same price and lowest. Can you please tell me the change required to implement this?

Comment: Andrew, this is solved. I posted the next step here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933235/price-compare-with-multiple-store-in-sql. Hoping you could help me out on this.. Thank you very much for a very inspiration script

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this requirement:

> I want result like this for n number of sellers

If you have a fixed, known number of columns for your results, there are several techniques to [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) your data. But if the number of columns is not known, you're in trouble. The SQL language really wants you to be able to describe the exact nature of the result set for the select list in terms of the number and types of columns up front.

It sounds like you can't do that. This leaves you with two options:

1. Query the data to know how many stores you have and their names, and then use that information to build a dynamic sql statement.
2. (Preferred option) Perform the pivot in client code.

Comment: What will be the pivot code, if i want to use only 3 given sellers ?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that would probably work well with a PIVOT.  Microsoft's docs are actually pretty useful on PIVOT and UNPIVOT.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Basically it allows you to pick a column, in your case SellerName, and pivot that out so that the elements of the column themselves become columns in the new result.  The values that go in the new "Ebay", "Amazon", etc. columns would be an aggregate that you choose - in this case the MAX or MIN or AVG of the price.

For the final "Lowest Price" column you'd likely be best served by doing a subquery in your main query which finds the lowest value per product/date and then joining that back in to get the SellerName.  Something like:

```
SELECT 
    Product_Price.Date
    ,Product_Price.Product
    ,Product_Price.MinimumSellerName
FROM
(SELECT 
MIN(Price) AS min_price
,Product
,Date
FROM Product_Price
GROUP BY
Product
,Date) min_price
INNER JOIN Product_Price
ON min_price.Product = Product_Price.Product
    AND min_price.Date = Product_Price.Date
```

Then just put the pivot around that and include the MinimumSellerName columnm, just like you include date and product.