# Price compare with multiple store in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
create table Products
    (
      id int,
      ProductName varchar(200),
      ProductCategory varchar(200),
      ProductImage varchar(200),
      ProductUri varchar(200),
    )

Insert into Products values(135, 'Product X', 'Digital Camera', Null, Null)
Insert into Products values(136, 'Product Y', 'Mobile', Null, Null)

create table Product_Price
    (
      id int,
      ProductId int,
      dt date,
      SellerName varchar(20),
      Available varchar(20),
      Offer varchar(20),      
      Price money,
      Shipping money
    )

insert into Product_Price values (1, 135,'2012-01-16','Sears','In Stock','30% discount',32.00,2.00)
insert into Product_Price values (2, 135,'2012-01-16','Amazon','In Stock',Null,30.00,NULL)
insert into Product_Price values (3, 135,'2012-01-16','eBay','Just 2 Left',Null,28.00,1.00)

insert into Product_Price values (4, 136,'2012-01-16','Sears','In Stock','30% discount',30.00,6.00)
insert into Product_Price values (5, 136,'2012-01-16','Amazon','In Stock',Null,28.00,4.00)
insert into Product_Price values (6, 136,'2012-01-16','eBay','Out Of stock',Null,Null,Null)
```

And i want result like this :

```
   ID   ProductName ProductCategory ProductImage    ProductUri  SearsTotal Price(Price+Shipping)    SearsAvailablity    SearsOffer  #Competitors    DifferencePercentage(Sears & others)    AmazonTotal Price(Price+Shipping)   AmazonAvailablity   AmazonOffer eBayTotal Price(Price+Shipping) eBayAvailablity eBayOffer
135 Product X   Digital Camera  NULL    NULL    34  In Stock    30% discount    2   15.25423729 30  In Stock    NULL    29  Just 2 Left NULL
136 Product Y   Mobile  NULL    NULL    36  In Stock    25% discount    1   12.5    32  In Stock    NULL    NULL    Out Of stock    NULL
```

Step 1 is here : [Product price comparison in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841022/product-price-comparison-in-sql/19842699)
My test is here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec1e7/6

Comment: So? you should have a select statement if you want some results?

Comment: I know that. here is the select statement with same type of demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec1e7/6 But i need to customize this demo as per the given source table above

Comment: what is wrong with your own result? can you be more spesific?

Comment: My result is good, but as i have 1,2 extra columns such as Shipping days which has differnt value across stores. Then group by generate new row for that. However want result as i show above

Comment: See this fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2210d/1 This is working fine. But as i add ShippingTime in group by it give multiple rows in output. The thing is i want ShippingTime in output for each stores same as given in source table

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab at this although I wasn't sure how you wanted to calculate your DifferencePercentage column, so you may want to look at that closer.

```
CREATE TABLE #tempProduct
(
    ID INT,
    SellerName VARCHAR(100),
    Total MONEY,
    Availability VARCHAR(100),
    Offer VARCHAR(100),
    Competitors INT
)

INSERT INTO #tempProduct (ID, SellerName, Total, Availability, Offer)
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, pp.SellerName, pp.Price + ISNULL(pp.Shipping,0), pp.Available, pp.Offer
FROM Products p
JOIN Product_Price pp
    ON p.id = pp.ProductId

-- Get Sears competitors
UPDATE tp
SET Competitors = pp.CompetitorCount
FROM #tempProduct tp
JOIN (
        SELECT ProductId, COUNT(sellerName) [CompetitorCount] 
        FROM Product_Price 
        WHERE SellerName <> 'Sears' AND Price + ISNULL(Shipping,0) IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY ProductId
    ) pp
    ON pp.ProductId = tp.ID
WHERE tp.SellerName = 'Sears'

 SELECT DISTINCT 
    p.id, 
    p.ProductName,
    p.ProductCategory, 
    p.ProductImage, 
    p.ProductUri, 
    stp.Total [SearsTotal], 
    stp.Availability [SearsAvailability], 
    stp.Offer [SearsOffer], 
    stp.Competitors [#Competitors],
    100 - (((ISNULL(etp.Total,0) + ISNULL(atp.Total, 0))/stp.Competitors)/stp.Total) * 100 [DifferencePercentage(Sears & others)], -- Not sure how you want to calculate price difference
    atp.Total, 
    atp.Availability [AmazonTotal], 
    atp.Offer [AmazonOffer], 
    etp.Total [eBayTotal], 
    etp.Availability [eBayAvailability], 
    etp.Offer [eBayOffer]
 FROM Products p
JOIN Product_Price pp
    ON pp.ProductId = p.ID
JOIN #tempProduct stp
    ON stp.ID = p.id
JOIN #tempProduct etp
    ON etp.ID = p.id
JOIN #tempProduct atp
    ON atp.ID = p.id
WHERE stp.SellerName = 'Sears'  
AND etp.SellerName = 'eBay'
AND atp.SellerName = 'Amazon'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is "possible", but it's getting pretty crazy. Don't try this at home!  You really need some sort of reporting tool to do this kind of thing.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cad2/47)

Building on the logic we used in the other post, we'll need one more variable.  It's going to build a string that selects the max of each of our pivoted columns. So we'll start with:

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols2 AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @COL_ALIASES AS VARCHAR(MAX)


Select @COL_ALIASES = ISNULL(@COL_ALIASES + ', ', '') +
            'Max(' + QUOTENAME(SellerName + '_TOTAL') + ') As ' + QUOTENAME(SellerName + '_TOTAL') + ', ' +
            'Max(' + QUOTENAME(SellerName + '_AVAILABLE') + ') As ' + QUOTENAME(SellerName + '_AVAILABLE')

            from #Product_Price




select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(SellerName + '_TOTAL')
                      FROM #Product_Price
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '')

select @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(SellerName + '_AVAILABLE')
                      FROM #Product_Price
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '')
```

Then we assemble the query string from all of that fun stuff:

```
select @query =
' select p.id ,
p.productname,' + + @COL_ALIASES + CHAR(10) +

' from Products p
inner join (
select
productId,
' + @cols + ',' + @cols2 + '
from
(
select
p1.id as ProductID,
p2.sellername + ''' + '_TOTAL' + ''' As TotalSeller,
p2.sellername + ''' + '_AVAILABLE' + ''' as AvailableSeller,
p2.price,
p2.available

from
products p1
inner join product_price p2
on p1.id = p2.productid ) t1
PIVOT (max(price)  for TotalSeller in (' + @cols + ')) t
PIVOT (max(available) for AvailableSeller in (' + @cols2 + ') ) u )
 pvt
ON p.id = pvt.productid
GROUP BY p.id,
p.productname
 '
```

And finally, we run it:

```
Exec sp_executesql @Query
```

You would just keep expanding on this logic to add your additional pivots.  You can see why I said this is getting crazy.  I did this much just because I kind of enjoyed the challenge, but I certainly wouldn't recommend trying to actually use this.  As folks have pointed out in other posts, you could expose yourself to SQL injection, and it would be a beast to maintain.  If I looked at this 6 months from now, I'd probably have no idea what the heck was going on in this query.